# django get id for traverse a list

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite, django-views

I want to convert my list into dict to have my id so I try this in my views

```
def img2(request):

    posts = Post.objects.all()
    i=[]
    for p in posts:
        print(p.id)
        i.append(p.id)
        #post={'id':str(p.id)}
    #print(i)
    '''def Convert(lst):
        res_dct = {str(lst[i]): lst[i] for i in range(0, len(lst), 1)}
        return res_dct   
    # Driver code
    d=Convert(i)'''
    d = {str(i[k]): i[k] for k in range(0, len(i), 1)}
    print(d)
    for j in d:
        print(j)
    return render(request, 'imgg.html', d)
```

then I want to display every id in HTML and this is my HTML file:

```
<h1>test</h1>

{% for n in d %}

<h3>{{n}}</h3>

{% endfor %}
```

Nothing happened and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: i think i have an other method share your views ,models and template ?

Comment: What did the print statement print out?

Comment: print(p.id) = all the id of my posts, print(d)= dict of my id

Answer (score 0):

this is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import Count
import posts

from .models import Post, PostImage

def blog_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog.html', {'posts':posts})

def detail_view(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    photos = PostImage.objects.filter(post=post)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {
        'post':post,
        'photos':photos
    })

def create_post_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        length = request.POST.get('length')
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        description = request.POST.get('description')

        post = Post.objects.create(
            title=title,
            description=description
        )
    
        for file_num in range(0, int(length)):
            PostImage.objects.create(
                post=post,
                images=request.FILES.get(f'images{file_num}')
            )

    return render(request, 'create-post.html')
def img(request,id):
    img=PostImage.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'img.html', {'img':img})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).